# How to update product attributes?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have thousands of products which have some common default values:

> page layout : No layout updates;  Visibility:Not Visible Individually;
>   categoies: empty,

Now I want to change these three attributes once like below:

> page layout : 1 column;  Visibility:Catalog, Search (4); categoies: 1,

I tried to finish it with below code, but it is not working.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->load();

foreach($collection as $items)
{  
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($items->getId());  
    $product->setVisibility(4);  
    $product->save();
    echo $product->getId().'<br>';        
}
```

Who can tell me what the problem is with my code?

I also tried to finish in database. But I do not know which table can control visibilibty, which table can control layout or category. (Using Magento 1.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this directly from the admin area:

Catalog -> Manage Product

Check the article you want to edit and then select "Change attributes" from "Actions" drop down menu.

You can now massively change attribute to your product

Cheers